# CSS: place content so that second child is centered

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way to place the content of a container such that it is the second element that appears to be centered, instead of simply centering all children?

So that in my example there would be 30px before the sidebar and 50px after the main-content, instead of having 40px on each side.

I can't just use absolute positioning, as I in the case that the main-content is to large, still want to be able to see the sidebar.

The point is that I have a sidebar, that isn't always visible, and when toggling it on, I do not want it to push the main-content, if there actually is room for it.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="sidebar" />
                <div className="main-content" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}

.sidebar {
 background: red;
 height: 100%;
 width: 20px;
 flex-shrink: 0;
}

.main-content {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That was a mighty shame. I just spent 5 minutes coding a response to this and it closed.

Comment: Can I re-open it somehow, because the linked question does not seem to solve my issue:)

Comment: How does it not answer your question ?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen the accepted answer - maybe it does solve my issue, I will give it a try:)

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ztc4pea6/) using Solution #3, make sure you understand the idea

Comment: @Que happens to me a LOT 

Comment: Thank you - Yeah, that was also the solution I decided to try out - and it works! I do however have to set the flex-shrink to a very high value, to make sure that the pseudo element wont cause the main-content to be smaller :)

Comment: @Que instead of writing an answer to a question try to think if this question might already have an answer. Then you can save yourself quite some time.